# How to tell if two line segments with a non-zero width intersect

Tags: language-agnostic, geometry, collision-detection

A line segment can be defined by a pair of points.  There are well-known algorithms for finding whether two line segments in 2D space intersect.  But what if we make it a bit trickier by adding a width to the line?

Imagine you have a line segment defined by a pair of points *and* a width.  What you end up with is a rectangle whose sides *are not necessarily aligned with the coordinate axes.*  (So you can't use the standard "rectangle overlap" functions.)  What would be the best way to determine if two such line segments overlap?

Comment: I presume this is not just for one pair of line segments - rather, you're looking for something analogous to the classic sweep line algorithm?

Comment: @Ram: I'm not familiar with "the classic sweep line algorithm".

Comment: here is a link, by way of wikipedia. http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/373/notes/x06-sweepline.pdf

Comment: So I asked the question because if its only two line segment "boxes" you care about, you could just treat it as sixteen separate intersection problems, right? The "boxes" intersect if any two pairs of lines intersect. Or did I misunderstand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use [The Method of Separating Axes](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MethodOfSeparatingAxes.pdf) to find out whether the rotated rectangles (thick line segments) overlap. This method is fast and simple.

Answer (score 0):

A line with a width can be regarded as two parallel lines, separated by the width that you're talking about.  So two lines which each have a width corresponds to four lines.  Just work out whether any of these 4 lines intersect and you're done, aren't you?

Update: A comment points out that this will miss overlapping parallel lines.  I think that's all it will miss, so that case could be handled as a special case.

Comment: this will miss overlapping parallel lines.

Comment: @BevynQ good point.  But I think that's all it will miss, so I've edited my answer to include your point.

Comment: It will miss near-parallel overlapping lines too.

Comment: @Andrew I disagree.  As long as the two lines are not parallel, then there will be intersection points (even if a long way off screen). I think the proper use of that information can always provide the right answer.

Comment: @Stochastically These are line segments, not infinite lines. See [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SH4B4.jpg) for what I'm talking about. The thick blue and thick green lines are not parallel and overlap, but the (thin red and thin yellow) parallel lines at their sides do not cross.

Comment: Another nasty edge case illustrated [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q28kS.jpg) is that the two red parallel lines of one thick blue line segment can fail to meet any edge of the bounding rectangle of the other (green) thick line segment. You have to check all edges against all other edges if you want to use the edges to check.

Comment: @AndrewC I'm pretty sure I could code up something, starting from the quadrilateral that is the intersection of the infinite line case, and then restricting to truncated portions (i.e. line segments) to work out if the two intersect or not, which is all that the question here asks for.  A lot of the programming that I do is mathematically oriented. Compared to some of the hairy numerical techniques that I've used in the past, this doesn't feel that difficult. But I have no idea how efficient this kind of approach will turn out to be. New thought, perhaps a rotation would help implementation.

Comment: I see what you mean now. That makes sense.